# Why does my python script work on desktop but not in programes

Tags: python

So I tried making my first ever script, for some reason the script works fine while im still on desktop, but when I enter a video game (In my example GTA V) the script doesn't input mouse movement, clicks or keyboard. Ive found some solutions online but non work for me... Any help?

```
from pydirectinput import *
import pyautogui
import pydirectinput
import time
import keyboard
import random
import win32api, win32con
import sys

while True:
   riba3 = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('riba3.png', confidence=0.5)
   riba2 = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('riba2.png', confidence=0.5)
   riba1 = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('riba1.png', confidence=0.5)
   if riba3:
      pyautogui.moveTo(riba3)
      pyautogui.click(clicks=3, interval=1)
      
   elif riba2:
       pyautogui.moveTo(riba2)
       pyautogui.click(clicks=3, interval=1)
          
   elif riba1:
       pyautogui.moveTo(riba1)
       pyautogui.click(clicks=3, interval=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the terminal you are using to run python file has admin access. I was stuck with the same problem but running the command prompt in admin mode and then launching the py file solved my problem.